# function doesn't return data in php

Tags: php

I have made this function

```
function paragraph_modifier($para)
{
  str_replace('-.b-', '</strong>', str_replace('-b-', '<strong>', $para));
  str_replace('-.i-', '</i>', str_replace('-i-', '<i>', $para));
  str_replace('-.u-', '</span>', str_replace('-u-', '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">', $para));
  str_replace('-n-', '<br />', $para);

  return $para;
}
```

When I call it like

```
paragraph_modifier($policies['policy']);
```

it doesn't return data neither it shows any replacing result. Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the return of `str_replace`:

```
function paragraph_modifier($para){
    $para = str_replace('-.b-', '</strong>', str_replace('-b-', '<strong>',  $para));
    $para = str_replace('-.i-', '</i>', str_replace('-i-', '<i>', $para));
    $para = str_replace('-.u-', '</span>', str_replace('-u-', '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">', $para));
    $para = str_replace('-n-', '<br />', $para);

    return $para;
}
```

Then you need to assign the returned variable:

```
$something = paragraph_modifier($policies['policy']);
```

Or to modify the passed variable, pass by reference and don't `return`:

```
function paragraph_modifier(&$para)
```

Comment: So, we always have to store it in a variable.

Comment: @Jeff so very idiot mistake I did, I didn't do $para = .before str_replace

Comment: Result of straight 13 hours of programming turns into rotten peace of meat after this mistake. Time for a nap xD